# How to create a Call Diagram for Excel macros?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, diagrams, uml

I have an Excel file with multiple VBA-Macros. For documentation purposes I want to create a UML [Call Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_diagram), or similar that represents which macro calls which other one.

Is there a way to automatically create one?

Comment: People have made tools for exactly this. Google "document vba project"  Here's one that costs money: http://www.aivosto.com/  Here's one that doesn't: http://www.contextures.com/ExcelTemplates/ExcelVBACodeDoc.zip

Comment: I believe `Application.Caller` will give you the name of the Sub() that calls another.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Engineer Toast](https://superuser.com/users/348859/engineer-toast)'s comment (and expanded with some screenshots of the respective tools):

> People have made tools for exactly this. Google "document vba project"
>   Here's one that costs money: [Aivosto](http://www.aivosto.com/project/enterprise.html) (Project Analyzer Enterprise Edition)
>   Here's one that doesn't: [contextures.com/ExcelTemplates/ExcelVBACodeDoc.zip](http://contextures.com/ExcelTemplates/ExcelVBACodeDoc.zip) (direct link)

### Project Analyzer screenshot

[image: Screenshot from the Aivosto homepage showing Project Analyzer Enterprise Edition]

### ExcelVBACodeDoc screenshot

[image: Screenshot showing ExcelVBACodeDoc output]

(I guess this is not exactly what you wanted, since it creates no diagram but rather a list of procedures)